# Using Python, able to iterate files from another directory but unable to read contents

Tags: python, loops, directory

I need to iterate through all the .txt files inside another directory from current directory and read the contents.

Am able to iterate thw filenames, but when tried to read the contents, the output is blabk while there is data in the files.

Comment: Please share code that demonstrates the problem and tell us more about the files you're reading.

Comment: The below is the code from 'user14944294'. The files am trying to iterate or read ia just a. txt file with few linea of a paragraph

Answer (score 1):

To do that here is an example of how to iterate on every text file in the current directory

```
# Import the module OS
import os

# Choose Current Directory
directory = os.getcwd()

# Iterate over every file in the directory
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    # get the full path by concatenating the file name with the directory
    path = directory + "\\" + filename
    # Check if this file is a text file
    if path.endswith(".txt"):
        # Open the text files in the path
        text_file = open(path, 'r')
        # Read and print the contents of these files (Including the Python Script)
        print(text_file.read())
```

You can change the current directory with any directory you need.

If you have a problem with other Directories try using double backslashes in the URL like this

```
directory = 'C:\\Users\\USER\\Desktop\\Text Files'
```

Comment: Tried this as well.. only the current directory files can be read.. while trying to read from other directory.. the reaponse is blank

Comment: How do you write the other directory's line?

Comment: I've Edited my answer, please check what I added and let me know if it works

Answer (score 0):

```py
for file in files :
 print(file)
 print("printing success file")
 k = open(extracted_files_path+file,"r")
 print(extracted_files_path + file)
 print("ending printing success file")
 print(k.read())
 print(type(file))
```

Output:

> printing success file  ending printing success file
> //below is blank, whereas the file contents are expected// <class
> 'str'>

The above is the code and the actual output I'm getting for the question - raven.